# Issues with 0 values using ggplot2 and geom_bar

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gradient

I’m building a bar plot with ggplot2 with the code below. I have two questions about this plot. Why does the ‘+ scale_y_log10()' create the weird 0 value below the rest of the plot? can that be removed? And probably an easier question how do you change the color of the gradient when using ‘fill’ with ggplot2 and ‘geom_bar’? I'm new working with ggplot2 so the syntax isn't the easiest, any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: 
I found the fix to the gradient.. heres what worked for me

```
bPlot + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "grey", mid ="lightgrey", high = "blue")
```

R Code:

```
# ggplot2 
bPlot <- ggplot(dat, aes(1:nrow(dat), dat$coverage, fill = dat$uniqueness)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + scale_y_log10()
bPlot + ylab("Coverage") + xlab("Length") + ggtitle("Covrage & Uniquness") + theme_bw()
```

[image: ggplot2]

> dput(dat)
>   structure(list(coverage = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 174L, 173L, 172L, 171L, 171L, 
>   172L, 172L, 170L, 170L, 168L, 169L, 169L, 168L, 169L, 175L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   279L, 276L, 278L, 279L, 277L, 276L, 282L, 286L, 291L, 269L, 269L, 
>   264L, 269L, 277L, 276L, 276L, 273L, 275L, 277L, 279L, 277L, 275L, 
>   271L, 265L, 265L, 240L, 240L, 242L, 242L, 241L, 239L, 239L, 240L, 
>   229L, 221L, 213L, 210L, 222L, 222L, 223L, 225L, 227L, 229L, 238L, 
>   239L, 239L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 245L, 250L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 
>   250L, 253L, 252L, 254L, 257L, 258L, 265L, 269L, 274L, 269L, 258L, 
>   266L, 272L, 286L, 283L, 291L, 310L, 383L, 480L, 500L, 514L, 523L, 
>   523L, 523L, 525L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 529L, 531L, 531L, 527L, 
>   521L, 469L, 424L, 412L, 413L, 412L, 410L, 410L, 409L, 405L, 403L, 
>   402L, 402L, 400L, 408L, 408L, 410L, 410L, 406L, 408L, 407L, 407L, 
>   402L, 397L, 393L, 394L, 394L, 388L, 390L, 390L, 390L, 391L, 394L, 
>   394L, 396L, 394L, 381L, 383L, 382L, 382L, 385L, 411L, 410L, 412L, 
>   408L, 403L, 401L, 396L, 397L, 397L, 395L, 399L, 398L, 399L, 398L, 
>   395L, 396L, 399L, 1035L, 4068L, 4058L, 4046L, 361L, 359L, 356L, 
>   353L, 352L, 363L, 363L, 346L, 343L, 336L, 332L, 329L, 327L, 309L, 
>   306L, 306L, 301L, 300L, 310L, 315L, 337L, 339L, 354L, 354L, 354L, 
>   354L, 354L, 356L, 354L, 351L, 354L, 344L, 343L, 336L, 334L, 331L, 
>   326L, 323L, 281L, 258L, 245L, 234L, 152L, 40L, 2473L, 2446L, 
>   1428L, 1449L, 1467L, 1488L, 1249L, 1250L, 1251L, 1201L, 1206L, 
>   1211L, 1213L, 1215L, 1175L, 132L, 124L, 108L, 111L, 129L, 134L, 
>   140L, 144L, 155L, 167L, 170L, 170L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 173L, 176L, 
>   177L, 177L, 180L, 135L, 137L, 137L, 140L, 141L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 
>   141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 142L, 141L, 141L, 145L, 145L, 146L, 145L, 
>   147L, 147L, 148L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 157L, 156L, 155L, 154L, 155L, 
>   155L, 166L, 167L, 167L, 167L, 169L, 169L, 172L, 176L, 185L, 191L, 
>   188L, 195L, 195L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 205L, 214L, 224L, 231L, 235L, 
>   239L, 239L, 239L, 233L, 238L, 240L, 242L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 194L, 189L, 173L, 158L, 
>   161L, 164L, 165L, 165L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 167L, 167L, 162L, 156L, 
>   158L, 158L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 155L, 153L, 152L, 154L, 154L, 157L, 
>   158L, 161L, 850L, 851L, 852L, 852L, 859L, 856L, 852L, 854L, 846L, 
>   854L, 155L, 155L, 156L, 162L, 174L, 184L, 191L, 192L, 191L, 195L, 
>   197L, 202L, 205L), uniqueness = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 0.956522, 0.96, 0.961538, 0.961538, 0.961538, 0.96, 
>   0.966667, 0.967742, 0.967742, 0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 
>   0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 0.967742, 0.966667, 0.966667, 
>   0.96875, 0.96875, 0.969697, 0.969697, 0.969697, 0.969697, 0.969697, 
>   0.969697, 0.969697, 0.970588, 0.970588, 0.971429, 0.946429, 0.95, 
>   0.95, 0.95, 0.95082, 0.949153, 0.948276, 0.948276, 0.948276, 
>   0.949153, 0.949153, 0.949153, 0.95082, 0.95082, 0.957447, 0.931034, 
>   0.928571, 0.933333, 0.931034, 0.931034, 0.933333, 0.933333, 0.931034, 
>   0.931034, 0.931034, 0.931034, 0.931034, 0.931034, 0.928571, 0.928571, 
>   0.925926, 0.925926, 0.925926, 0.925926, 0.925926, 0.923077, 0.925926, 
>   0.925926, 0.925926, 0.925926, 0.925926, 0.925926, 0.925926, 0.925926, 
>   0.925926, 0.928571, 0.931818, 0.931818, 0.951613, 0.952381, 0.952381, 
>   0.953125, 0.954545, 0.955224, 0.954545, 0.954545, 0.954545, 0.954545, 
>   0.953846, 0.955224, 0.955882, 0.955224, 0.954545, 0.955224, 0.955224, 
>   0.955224, 0.964286, 0.964286, 0.963636, 0.962963, 0.962963, 0.962963, 
>   0.962963, 0.962963, 0.962963, 0.962963, 0.945455, 0.963636, 0.960784, 
>   0.960784, 0.960784, 0.960784, 0.960784, 0.960784, 0.969697, 0.969697, 
>   0.969697, 0.969697, 0.970588, 0.969697, 0.969697, 0.96875, 0.96875, 
>   0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 
>   0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 0.96875, 
>   0.96875, 0.96875, 0.969697, 0.969697, 0.969697, 0.969697, 0.969697, 
>   0.969697, 0.969697, 0.96875, 0.967742, 0.967742, 0.967742, 0.967742, 
>   0.967742, 0.958333, 0.959184, 0.959184, 0.958333, 0.958333, 0.958333, 
>   0.958333, 0.959184, 0.959184, 0.959184, 0.959184, 0.959184, 0.959184, 
>   0.959184, 0.951613, 0.951613, 0.951613, 0.95082, 0.95082, 0.95082, 
>   0.95082, 0.95082, 0.95082, 0.95082, 0.95082, 0.95082, 0.95082, 
>   0.95082, 0.951613, 0.951613, 0.951613, 0.951613, 0.951613, 0.951613, 
>   0.953125, 0.952381, 0.952381, 0.95, 0.951613, 0.951613, 0.951613, 
>   0.951613, 0.951613, 0.936508, 0.936508, 0.951613, 0.951613, 0.951613, 
>   0.951613, 0.951613, 0.951613, 0.936508, 0.936508, 0.935484, 0.935484, 
>   0.888889, 0.888889, 0.888889, 0.888889, 0.883333, 0.898305, 0.898305, 
>   0.898305, 0.898305, 0.898305, 0.898305, 0.9, 0.898305, 0.898305, 
>   0.896552, 0.896552, 0.896552, 0.890625, 0.670588, 0.674419, 0.670588, 
>   0.830986, 0.830986, 0.816901, 0.819444, 0.819444, 0.819444, 0.819444, 
>   0.816901, 0.819444, 0.819444, 0.813333, 0.808219, 0.808219, 0.819444, 
>   0.819444, 0.819444, 0.819444, 0.816901, 0.194631, 0.195286, 0.191419, 
>   0.194079, 0.103691, 0.103873, 0.103691, 0.109948, 0.11014, 0.11014, 
>   0.110333, 0.113074, 0.113074, 0.113074, 0.114841, 0.114437, 0.110721, 
>   0.110915, 0.109541, 0.108772, 0.11014, 0.111702, 0.110915, 0.110915, 
>   0.110915, 0.1125, 0.0906516, 0.0911681, 0.0981308, 0.0978261, 
>   0.10061, 0.100152, 0.175066, 0.175066, 0.175532, 0.176316, 0.176316, 
>   0.17801, 0.17942, 0.180628, 0.180628, 0.196023, 0.200573, 0.921053, 
>   0.921053, 0.921053, 0.92, 0.922078, 0.923077, 0.923077, 0.911392, 
>   0.911392, 0.911392, 0.946667, 0.945946, 0.946667, 0.942857, 0.942857, 
>   0.942857, 0.90411, 0.90411, 0.984848, 0.984615, 0.984615, 0.984848, 
>   0.984615, 0.984615, 0.984615, 0.984848, 0.984615, 0.984375, 0.984375, 
>   0.984375, 0.984375, 0.984375, 0.984375, 0.984375, 0.984375, 0.984375, 
>   0.984375, 0.984375, 0.984615, 0.984848, 0.984615, 0.984615, 0.984615, 
>   0.984615, 0.985294, 0.985294, 0.985294, 0.985294, 0.985294, 0.985507, 
>   0.985714, 0.985714, 0.985714, 0.985714, 0.985507, 0.985507, 0.985507, 
>   0.985714, 0.985714, 0.985507, 0.985507, 0.985507, 0.985507, 0.985714, 
>   0.985915, 0.985714, 0.985915, 0.985915, 0.985915, 0.985714, 0.985714, 
>   0.985714, 0.985714, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>   0.984848, 0.985075, 0.985075, 0.985075, 0.985075, 0.984848, 0.984848, 
>   0.984848, 0.984848, 0.984848, 0.984375, 0.984127, 0.984127, 0.382716, 
>   0.382716, 0.380368, 0.382716, 0.378882, 0.371951, 0.371951, 0.374233, 
>   0.381818, 0.379518, 0.378049, 0.36747, 0.363095, 0.361446, 0.353659, 
>   0.353659, 0.353659, 0.353659, 0.353659, 0.353659, 0.349693, 0.347561, 
>   0.347561, 0.349693, 0.354037, 0.354037, 0.35625, 0.35625, 0.3625, 
>   0.36646, 0.36875, 0.983333, 0.983607)), .Names = c("coverage", 
>   "uniqueness"), row.names = c(NA, 500L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: It's not 0, it's 1. Put breaks in to check `scale_y_log10(breaks = c(1,10,100))` .   Also, there are zeros in `dat$coverage`. In R, log10(0) = -Inf. So you might need to remove the zeros from the data file.

Comment: I thought that 0's might be an issue with log10()... how is this issue normally handled? just change 0's to .001 or 0 to 1's whats the best approach

Comment: One way is to replace them with `NA`. That way, there will be a gap instead of a bar. `dat$New_coverage = ifelse(dat$coverage == 0, NA, dat$coverage)`

Comment: since your coverage seems to take on integer values probably the simplest thing is to use `bPlot <- ggplot(dat, aes(1:nrow(dat), 1+coverage, fill = uniqueness)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + scale_y_log10()` ...

Comment: @Sandy, THANK YOU!